# Laravel regex validation prevent special charcters

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want to prevent these characters /:?“<>| inside string by Laravel validation how I can do this?

Comment: What did you try with so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex/ not_regex patterns. For example:

```
'email' => 'not_regex:/^.+$/i'
```